# Ember - retrieve selected menu item and load a template accordingly

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-framework

I have designed a page (home page) using ember and running over nodeJS. On the left side of this home page, I have a vertical menu. All the menu items (values) are loaded dynamically using a webservice.

```
            {{#each}}
                {{#linkTo 'category' this}}
                    <ul id="{{unbound id}}" class="menu" onclick="popMenu('{{unbound title}}', '{{unbound id}}')">
                        <div id="{{unbound title}}">{{unbound title}}</div>
                    </ul>
                {{/linkTo}}
            {{/each}}
```

When user clicks on any of these menu items, a 'category' template will be called.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("category", {path: ':title'});
});

App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
       console.log('test');
    }
});
```

I tested the above code in my local environment (localhost:3000). When user clicks any menu item, 'category' template is loaded successfully with a url change (localhost:3000/#/SELECTED_TITLE_VALUE).

However, my 'test' logs are not printed in console (which I have in my CategoryRoute. it makes that my route function is not called).

Can anyone please guide me on the following questions:
- When user clicks any menu item, the new templates are rendered properly (with a proper url changes). However, my 'CategoryRoute' is not properly called?

My main goal is to:

- When user clicks this left menu, I have to retrieve the **selected_menu_item_id** and call a new webservice based on the selected_menu_item_id.
- I have to use this webservice response, and load few information in the newly rendered template.

Can someone please guide the controllers and model for my above scenario. Some code snippets will be very helpful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the latest answers/modifications/clarifications of the question, here is another example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UQIbEjU/1/edit

The main part is

```
var selectedCategoryPath = null;
var categoryInformation = null;
App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
       selectedCategoryPath = transition.providedModels.category.id; //retrieves the value of selected menu id
       var category = Categories.create();
       categoryInformation= category.getCategoryInformation(); //When user clicks any menu item, a new template should be loaded with an webservice response. currently I have replaced my webservice code with an model data
       console.log(categoryInformation);
      this.set("categoryInfo",categoryInformation);
       return categoryInformation;
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        controller.set('categoryInfo', this.get("categoryInfo"));
    }
});

App.CategoryController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  categoryInfo:null
});
```

So this works because a controller with a property `categoryInfo` has been created and the data (`category.getCategoryInformation();`) from `beforeModel` is set to that property. This is required because the template was

```
{{categoryInfo.description}}
```

Also in this case the model (within the `setupController`) is the one assigned by the `link-to` which is `{id: 1, title: "item 1"}`, `{id: 2, title: "item 2"}` and so on. No `categoryInfo`property was  present, so the `categoryInfo` property of the controller had to be set.

In the latest resolution, you call

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
        this._super(controller, categoryInformation);
    }
```

the `categoryInformation` data is assigned as `model` to the default controller and by modifying the template as you nicely did, the `{{description}}` now exists as the `model/categoryInformation` includes this information.

Answer (score 2):

model hook of the route is only fired when the transition is from url, otherwise, *linkto helper* and *transisionTo method* don't fire this hook because normally you provide the model i.e.

```
{{#link-to 'category' this}}
```

The this keyword represents the model for the route...

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Good luck

Comment: use `#link-to`, `linkTo` is deprecated

Comment: Thanks Edu. Can you please guide me on the following questions: (1) When user clicks my left menu, I have to retrieve the selected_menu_item_id or selected_menu_item_value in router. And then call a new webservice based on the selected_menu_item_id. How can I get the selected_menu_item_value in router?
(2) I have to use the webservice response, and load few information in the newly rendered template. Do I need controller in router for this or can I directly call a model (to retrieve webservice).

Comment: @Kamal you can use the afterModel hook for this pupose, if you could provide a JSFiddle I could help more easily

Comment: Thanks for the help Edu. Actually now I made my webservice call in beforeModel function. So that before rendering templates, this will call my webservice and retrieve all values. Thanks for your guidance. It really helped me :)